# Trying to open Outlook using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook

I have created an application in ASP.NET using VB. I have written following code.

It is giving an error in localhost but when I am running it from my application, it is working fine.

I have checked DCOMCNFG --> Outlook/Office entry is not present.

Please advise me how to open Outlook with the attachment from my application at localhost/server?

```
ByVal recipients As List(Of String),
   ByVal smtpAddress As String,
   ByVal attachments As List(Of String))

    ' Create a new MailItem and set the To, Subject, and Body properties.
    'Dim application As New Outlook.Application
    Dim application As New Outlook.Application()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

    Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)

    ' Set up all the recipients.
    For Each recipient In recipients
        newMail.Recipients.Add(recipient)
    Next

    If newMail.Recipients.ResolveAll() Then
        newMail.Subject = subject
        newMail.Body = body
        For Each attachment As String In attachments
            newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue)
        Next
    End If

    newMail.Display(True)
```

Comment: If you are hoping to invoke Outlook on the client machine, that is not possible from code on the server. Just imagine if any web site could run any program on the computer that views it. If you are hoping to invoke Outlook on the web server, again you are out of luck because Office applications cannot be reliably used that way: they are designed to have an interactive UI, which a web server does not have. However, you can send email from the server; the [System.Net.Mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/default.aspx) site covers the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use any third-party components that can deal with .pst files without Outlook involved.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.